# Run a program using NVIDIA dedicated GPU only when plugged into power

Tags: windows, laptop, battery, nvidia-graphics-card, switchable-graphics

Under 3d Settings in NVIDIA's control panel, it allows me to choose whether specific programs always start using the integrated graphics on my CPU or the dedicated GTX 960M.

Can I create a condition where the program opens with my GPU when my laptop is plugged into AC by default, and the same program opens with integrated graphics when it is on battery power by default?

Comment: Interesting question. :)

Comment: A good one. Integrated GPU is brutally under-powered for even normal dekstop apps on high resolution displays and stuttering & low-framerates when even just editing diagrams is common. But forcing the dedicated GPU to be used hurts battery life when not plugged in.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately, the requested configuration is unsupported.

The only company that allows such setup options would be AMD's Enduro implementation which allows GPU selection based on power supply.