# Set default graphics processor for windows 10 laptop

Tags: windows-10, laptop, gpu

We have a Lenovo Y40 laptop.  It has an AMD Radeon graphics processor as well as an integrated Intel GPU.  Windows 10 is the OS.

It seems that Windows 10 lets me assign a graphics card on a program-by-program basis using Settings --> Display --> Graphics Setttings as shown in the picture.

[image: Specifying graphics preference per program]

Presumably programs that are not assigned use the "System default" GPU.  It seems that default is the Intel, even when the machine is plugged in.

Is there a way to change which GPU is used by default?  Is there a way to make the default depend on whether the laptop is running on battery on mains?

Comment: I did find two similar questions. https://superuser.com/questions/1092681/how-do-i-permanently-enable-the-external-video-card-in-windows  is essentially the same question, but the only answer is in reference to NVIDIA GPUs, not AMD.  https://superuser.com/questions/1055905/run-a-program-using-nvidia-dedicated-gpu-only-when-plugged-into-power is about NVIDIA GPUs.

Comment: AMD has a Control Panel.  What other testing have you done?

Comment: Yes, AMD has a control panel for the Radeon.  However, it is not clear to me whether it is possible to use this control panel to influence the OS's choice of default. Nor is it clear how to use AMD's control panel to make the Radeon the default processor.  I have tried messing with the power profile, however that did not seem to affect the default GPU.